# What is the difference between these ES6 import statements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

`import { A, B, C } from 'somecomponent/components'`

```
import { A } from "somecomponent/components/A";
import { B } from "somecomponent/components/B";
import { C } from "somecomponent/components/C";
```

Does both the import statements above and below import only A, B, C? Is there any difference between these statements? Is there a preference to use either of them?

Comment: What environment are you running these in?

Comment: If you were importing `A`, `B` and `C` separately from `'somecomponent/components'`, then they would be the same. However, you're importing from three different modules (`/A`, `/B`, `/C`), which may or may not be the same as the other.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both imports do import `A`, `B` and `C` into the current module. However, the first imports them from one module, the second imports them from three different modules - which might have different values.

The two ways are only equivalent if - and only if - the module at `'somecomponent/components'` does

```
export { A } from "somecomponent/components/A";
export { B } from "somecomponent/components/B";
export { C } from "somecomponent/components/C";
```

(and iff these resolve to the same modules).

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference whatsoever. And yes, only `A`, `B`, and `C` are visible to you.

As for preference... whatever you like. Myself, less typing is better.

Comment: How can you say there is not difference if you don't know how the four modules are implemented?